# проблема с mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

я пытаюсь на linux установить phpmyadmin. Но при установке выкидывает ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрел как ее решать. Говорят что нужно создать файл. Я его создал, но еще нужно дать разрешение. Я так же дал его. Но все равно выскакивает эта ошибка.
Ниже разрешение файла.
[image: x]

Comment: Текст в виде картинки - очень, ОЧЕНЬ плохо.

Comment: `ps aux | grep mysql` в студию, от этого будем дальше смотреть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл это сообщения (про невозможность соединения на локальном сокете) заключается вот в чём:

1. Инсталлятор проверяет наличие MySQL на вашем компе.
2. Для этого он **пытается** установить соединение с сервером MySQL
3. Соединение устанавливается с помощью механизма сокетов.
4. На вашем компе инсталлятор не нашёл соответствующий сокет.
5. Вывод: на Вашем компе нет **работающего** сервера MySQL.

Совет простой: установите сервер! Если он уже установлен, то запустите его. Если он уже запущен, проверьте права доступа к серверу - кто может к нему логиниться?